# Check if state of dropdown has changed

Tags: angularjs, select

I am using `ng-options` to display drop-down with options. Suppose I have three options in it for example option1, option2, option3.By default option1 is selected, now if a user selects option2, then `$pristine` becomes `False` and again if he selects option1 then from angularjs's prospective `$pristine` should be false but according to user he has not changed the option.So I was looking for a way to detect this change

Comment: can you post what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Js fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xLjjrsy5/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form name="myForm">
      {{myForm.$pristine}}
      <select ng-model='list' ng-options='item.name for item in data'>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

***JS code***

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'test'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'test1'
    }];
    $scope.list = $scope.data[0];
    $scope.$watch('list', function(o, n) {
      if ($scope.list == $scope.data[0])
        $scope.myForm.$pristine = true;
    })
  });
```

You have add watch on your list model then this can be achieved

Comment: This can be done in ng-change itself, no need to use extra $watch

Comment: @RohanKawade then you can use method to set it do default `$scope.myForm.$setPristine(true);` refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what ng-change is for.

Usage would be like this (added $index to show you another option):

> HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="listController">
        <form name="myForm">
            <select ng-model="currOption"
                    ng-options='item.name for item in data'
                    ng-change="optionChanged(currOption, $index)">
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('listController', function($scope) {
         $scope.data = [{
             id: 1,
             name: 'option1'
         }, {
             id: 2,
             name: 'option2'
         }, {
             id: 3,
             name: 'option3'
         }];

        $scope.optionChanged(option, index) {
            // option = the selection the user just made.
            // index = the index of the selection in your data. I.E. $scope.data[index]
        };
});
```

Comment: But still the $pristine condition remains false.

Comment: @RohanKawade If you want to set it to true you can call `myform.$setPristine();` in 
 the`$scope.optionChanged` function.